# How to attach a context menu to a button

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, toolbar, dhtmlx

I'm trying to attach a context menu to a button on my toolbar.

Here is my code:

```
contex_order = new dhtmlXMenuObject();
contex_order.renderAsContextMenu();
contex_order.loadStruct(cont_m);
...
            toolbarOrder = new dhtmlXToolbarObject("tab_ord");
            toolbarOrder.setIconsPath("dhtmlx/codebase/imgs/");
            toolbarOrder.attachEvent("onClick", function(id){
if (id=="save")
    contex_order.showContextMenu(100,50)
            });
```

But clicking on that button doesn't make the context menu show up. There is no error in the browser console, just nothing.

Did anyone have such kind of a problem? How can I make the menu be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try to call the  showContextMenu() method with the timeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  contex_order.showContextMenu(100,50)
}, 50)
```

as the menu shows up at the same time with the button click this button click closes the menu at the same time.